# React Native android back button (phone button)

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I want to change or disable the android back button (the phone back button, not the app). If I load the new screen with this.props.navigator.push or .resetTo it works fine but in this situation I need to use this.props.navigator.showModal.

When I do it this way, it doesn't trigger handleBackPress (console.log() confirms this). Instead it just goes to the previous screen but I need it to close the modal or disable the button, I don't want it to go to previous screen

```
onNavigatorEvent(event) {
    console.log("event ", event)
    try{
        switch (event.id) {
            case 'willAppear':
                this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
                console.log("added")
                break;
            case 'willDisappear':
                this.backHandler.remove();
                console.log("removed")
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (ex) {
        console.log('VerifiedComponent::onNavigatorEvent: ' + ex);
    }
}

handleBackPress = () => {
    console.log("back")
    this.props.navigator.dismissAllModals({
        animationType: 'slide-down'
    })
    return true;
}
```

after the screen loaded, the back button was pressed

[image: console.log]

Comment: just return false in BackHandler.addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

You should override backbutton in RNN:

```
navigator.showModal({
        screen: 'xxxx',
        overrideBackPress: true,
}
```

Then you can access check:

```
if (event.id === 'backPress') {
    // do something
}
```